# Elasticity function of a given demand function

Tags: calculus

$$
q=D(x)=\frac{300}{x}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text { (given ) }
$$
as we know
$$
\begin{array}{l}
E(x)=\dfrac{-\frac{d q}{d x}}{\frac{q}{x}} \\
\dfrac{d q}{d x}=\dfrac{-300}{x^{2}}
\end{array}
$$
$$
E(x)=-\left(-\frac{300}{x^{2}} \times \frac{x \times x}{300}\right)=1
$$

The demand function is given
$D(x) = 300/x$
See where am i going wrong
I used
$E(x)= ( -{\rm d}q/{\rm d}x)/(q/x)$
${\rm d}q/{\rm d}x= -300/x^2$
$E(x)= 1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Ok sure please help me out now

Answer (score 1):

The formula is $$\epsilon=|\frac{dQ/Q}{dP/P}|=|\frac{dQ}{dP}\frac{P}{Q}|$$

Now

$$Q=300/P$$
$$\frac{dQ}{dP}=-300/P^2$$
$$\epsilon=|\frac{dQ}{dP}\frac{P}{Q}|=|-300/P^2\times P/Q|=|-300/PQ|=|-1|=1$$

Comment: So i did it right , you mean